# Video playing automatically in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

Hi I have a webview and when i tried to load the video files in that , it starts playing the video automatically without user intervention. And also the play button is still displayed in webview (video is playing behind that). I am using the following code to load the URL

```
NSURL*  url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest*   request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Can you tell me how to disable the play button OR the Video should start playing only after the user taps the play button ??

Comment: Do you really need to use a UIWebView?.. If you have the URL of a video, you could use MPMoviewPlayerConroller / MPMoviewPlayerViewController for more control over playback

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have planned to use the webview only. I have seen some examples for playing the video files using some other frameworks.But still I want to use the WebView only . Any idea?

Comment: you could create a web page template with HTML5-video tag (does provide a lot of options for auto play, airplay and so on) and javascript-enabled playback controls and inject the URL from obj c

Comment: I think the webview video playing best suited by creating thumb of video in the webview(like wise in youtube site). While you click on that thumb it will play the video in your webview itself. Try the posted code.

Comment: Ya. I did the same. The Video is playing without pressing the thumb. I want to remove that OR the video should start playing after i press play button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (void)videoThumb:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
          NSString *embedHTML = @"\
          <html><head>\
          <style type=\"text/css\">\
          body {\
          background-color: transparent;
          color: white;
          }\
          </style>\
          </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
          <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
          width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
          </body></html>";


  NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width,frame.size.height];

  [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
  [self.view addSubview:webView];
  [webView release];
}

//Include above function to your page and call it by passing the urlstring
[self videoThumb:url:frame];


//frame : this parameter needs the size of the thumb you want to use.
```

I hope this may help you and better way for your purpose.

Comment: this answer works but it doesn't resize if you change from portrait to landscape, how would you deal with that?

Comment: how can you make the video to play without tapping the play button?

Comment: Your answer working fine but getting problem in thimble

Comment: @Joge what problem are you facing getting the Thumbnail?

Comment: I have getting problem in webview video tumble but now It's working fine .. Thanks u so much .. take your Upvote :)

Comment: @Joge
Thanks, if any problem in anything regard to iOS do concern with me :)

Comment: Can I know we are passing here "frame.size.width,frame.size.height". How can I get 100% fit content in webview frame

Comment: @Joge please just make the embdedHTML string parametrized and pass the height and width from frame.width, frame.height

Comment: @Kuldeep Thanks for the code, its working fine with .mp4 files but having problem with .avi files, have you ever try to play .avi file?

Comment: This is not working in swift3. How to stop autoplay videos using UIWebView ?