# Is It Possible To Interact With UIWebView Without Touch?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, url, uiwebview

I'm trying to interact with a loaded page in a UIWebView without touching the screen. I have tried mediaplaybackrequiresuseraction with no success.  I have also tried the method provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510429/how-can-i-start-a-youtube-video-without-the-user-touching-the-uiwebview-itself?lq=1), but apparently it doesn't work in ios 6.  I'm trying to load [this](http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1683318714001?bckey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBPHZ2UIrFX2-wdCLTYNyMNn&bclid=1644543007001&bctid=2238216269001) url and make the player start playing.  Does anyone know how to make this work ios 6?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


  int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

  NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"link"];
  //storyLink is various form of http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1683318714001?bckey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBPHZ2UIrFX2-wdCLTYNyMNn&bclid=1644543007001&bctid=2238216269001 with different bctid=value

  NSURL *kitcoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:storyLink];
  NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:kitcoURL];
  [videoScreen setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  [videoScreen setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
  [videoScreen loadRequest:requestURL];

 }
```

//Method not working in ios6

```
 - (UIButton *)findButtonInView:(UIView *)view {
UIButton *button = nil;

if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
return (UIButton *)view;
}

if (view.subviews && [view.subviews count] > 0) {
for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
  button = [self findButtonInView:subview];
  if (button) return button;
}
}

return button;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView {
  UIButton *b = [self findButtonInView:_webView];
  [b sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 }
```

EDIT
//videoScreen is my UIWebView

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *urlString = @"http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1683318714001?bckey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBPHZ2UIrFX2-wdCLTYNyMNn&bclid=1644543007001&bctid=2238216269001";

NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"bckey=([^&]*)" options:0 error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:urlString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, urlString.length)];
NSString *bckey = [urlString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"bctid=([0-9]*)" options:0 error:&error];
match = [regex firstMatchInString:urlString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, urlString.length)];
NSString *bctid = [urlString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

NSString *newUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/htmlFederated?&playerKey=%@&videoID=%@", bckey, bctid];

[videoScreen loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newUrlString]]];

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
if (!webView.isLoading)
{
    [self checkForVideoReady];
}

}
 // Checking player object for ready. If it ready - starting video. Otherwise waiting 1 second 
- (void)checkForVideoReady
{
    if (![[videoScreen stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"player.ready"]   isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkForVideoReady) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
   }
   else
   {
        [videoScreen stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"player.videoPlayer.playButton.element.click();"];
   }
 }
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` property on `UIWebView` is for?

Comment: mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction causes crash due to unrecognized selector.  Please check edit.

Comment: Well, you'll have to use `setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO`. videoScreen has to be a `UIWebView`, too.

Comment: Using setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO doesn't cause crash, but media doesn't play

Comment: Did you set delegate of UIWebView?

Comment: just use  html stuff as I posted the answer you just need to copy&paste this. And you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method for find button in view based on HTML 5 Youtube videos.
I found workaround for your problem, it's not elegant, but working.

Your link

> http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1683318714001?bckey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBPHZ2UIrFX2-wdCLTYNyMNn&bclid=1644543007001&bctid=2238216269001

downloads page with flash object. And as far as I know there is no way to start playing it using JS or `UIWebView`.
After researching requests I saw that `UIWebView` query for another url:

> http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/htmlFederated?&width=966&height=546&flashID=myExperience&bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&playerID=1683318714001&playerKey=AQ~~%2CAAAAC59qSJk~%2CvyxcsD3OtBPHZ2UIrFX2-wdCLTYNyMNn&isVid=true&isUI=true&dynamicStreaming=true&autoStart=true&debuggerID=&videoID=2238216269001&%40videoPlayer=2238216269001&lineupID=1644543007001&startTime=1364279975091&refURL=not%20available&%40videoPlayer=2238216269001

The second one is more interesting, because we can access to `player` variable and start video with using JavaScript.

So we need to convert initial URL. Seems like we have only 2 important parameters in URL - `bckey` and `bctid`:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1683318714001?bckey=AQ~~,AAAAC59qSJk~,vyxcsD3OtBPHZ2UIrFX2-wdCLTYNyMNn&bclid=1644543007001&bctid=2238216269001";

NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"bckey=([^&]*)" options:0 error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:urlString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, urlString.length)];
NSString *bckey = [urlString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"bctid=([0-9]*)" options:0 error:&error];
match = [regex firstMatchInString:urlString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, urlString.length)];
NSString *bctid = [urlString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

NSString *newUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/htmlFederated?&playerKey=%@&videoID=%@", bckey, bctid];
```

And load new URL

```
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newUrlString]]];
```

After URL is loading we have access to `player` object. This object can tell when video is ready to play and start playback

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if (!webView.isLoading)
    {
        [self checkForVideoReady];
    }

}
// Checking player object for ready. If it ready - starting video. Otherwise waiting 1 second 
- (void)checkForVideoReady
{
    if (![[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"player.ready"] isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(checkForVideoReady) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }
    else
    {
        [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"player.videoPlayer.playButton.element.click();"];
    }
}
```

I know that this is not elegant, maybe someone will find a way how to improve it.
Feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Your answer makes a lot of sense but it didn't work when I implemented it.  Is there something I'm missing? Please check edit.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to play a song only, as & when webview loads. Then you need to invoke play function in

```
 `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    // Do whatever you want here
   // play song
}`
```

but make sure you have assigned delegate to your webview like this

```
<UIWebView_object>.delegate = self;
```

This will automatically play a song as & when webview loads

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I don't understand how your answer is different from what I am already doing.  Could you expound?

Comment: @B.Money , Yes,Whatever I understood from your question, you want to play a song from UIWebView without touching it, that is as soon as the app loads, correct?

Answer (score 1):

you ca have "autoplay" "on" in the javascript of the web page you are loading in web view.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)videoThumb:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {
      NSString *embedHTML = @"\
      <html><head>\
      <style type=\"text/css\">\
      body {\
      background-color: transparent;
      color: white;
      }\
      </style>\
      </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
      <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
      width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
      </body></html>";


   NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width,frame.size.height];

  [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
  [self.view addSubview:webView];
  [webView release];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Include above function to your page and call it by passing the urlstring
    //frame : this parameter needs the size of the thumb you want to use.
    [self videoThumb:url:frame];
}
```

Just call the videoThumb function by passing the url you want to play for and just done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992735/video-playing-automatically-in-uiwebview/9993698#comment22222207_9993698 refer same question and answer on this link visit it will be helpful to you.